# quiero imprimir la columna dada x un usuario pero cuando digito cual quiero imprimir siempre me imprime la ultima columna

Tags: c#, matriz

El ejercicio es en consola c# y lo estoy haciendo en con algunos métodos será q me ayudan se los agradecería mucho
Cuando digito el número de la columna que deseo imprimir este siempre me imprime la ultima y no se porque

//Imprimir una columna dada por el usuario

const int N = 3

Lo declare con una constante entera N que es igual a 3

```
    static void llenar (int[,] columna)
    {
        for (int f = 0; f < N; f++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < N; c++)
            {
                Console.Write("Ingrese el dato de la posicion [" +f+ "," +c+ "]:");
                columna[f, c] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());   
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

   static void PedirCol(int[,] columna)
    {
        int x=0;

        Console.Write("Que Columna desea Imprimir: ");
        x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int f = 0; f < N; f++)
        {
            int col= 0;

            for (int c = 0; c < N; c++)
            {
                
                col = columna[f, c];
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("El Resultado es: {0} ", col);
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] columna = new int[N, N];

        llenar(columna);
        ImpMatriz(columna);
        PedirCol(columna);


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que a pesar que le solicitas al usuario la columna que desea imprimir, nunca la utilizas en el recorrido de la matriz. Lo que estás haciendo en el método de PedirCol() es recorrer la matriz completa y sobreescribiendo la variable col hasta que ya no quedan columnas, es por esto que siempre obtienes el último valor.
La solución es mucho más sencilla, dado que ya conoces cual es la columna que deseas imprimir, únicamente es necesario iterar sobre las filas:

```
static void PedirCol(int[,] columna)
{
    Console.Write("Que Columna desea Imprimir: ");
    var x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    for (int c = 0; c < columna.GetLength(0); c++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("El Resultado es: {0} ", columna[c, x]);
    }
}
```

Adicionalmente, utilizar el método de GetLength es una mejor solución, ya que permitirá que el algoritmo funcione aún con matrices rectangulares y sin tener que quemar el dato.